# Material UI Menu component is not getting the styles applied in react

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I am new to `material-UI` , Here I have menu compoent which looks like,

```
<Menu
    classes={{ paper: css.paperMenu }}
    className={classNames({
      [css.menuMarginTop]: true
    })}

>

.menuMarginTop {
  margin-top: 14px;
}
```

also has other props as well. Now, when I am trying to add the styles on the basis of prop then the style `menuMarginTop` is not getting applied, can any one let me know how to do this ?.

Thanks.

Comment: did you try suggested answers?

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you are using normal CSS, but material-UI uses JSS underlying as their styling solutions, You can read about there styling solutions [here](https://material-ui.com/styles/basics/), and how to customize the CSS of components [here](https://material-ui.com/customization/components/).

You Can do this in your case

```
import Menu from "@material-ui/core/Menu";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  paperMenu: {
    color: "red"
  },
  menuMarginTop: {
    color: "blue"
  }
}));

export default function App(props) {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <Menu
      classes={{ paper: classes.paperMenu }}
      className={classes.menuMarginTop}
    />
  );
}
```

Here, `classes.paperMenu` will override the underlying paper(component) class, and  `menuMarginTop` will get applied to the root element of the Menu component.
`Material-UI` generate unique Class name randomly at runtime so you can't rely on fixed class name like other libraries, you can only override the underlying class using `classes` props, more info in the above links

Remember this is one of the ways to override the classes there are other ways as well like HIgher order component `withStyles`, `withTheme` etc, above links will provide you with enough information

Comment: `classes.menuMarginTop` didn't work

Comment: `makeStyles` is now deprecated and should not be used.